# Which end of the cucumber should I save for later?

Tags: storage-method, vegetables, cucumbers

When using only half of a cucumber, which end of the cucumber should I save for later use - the stem end or the blossom end?

Comment: Split it lengthwise and avoid the dilemma altogether.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I am curious to cut a cucumber in half and put both halves in the fridge and check which lasts longer...

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Won't it dry out much more quickly like that?

Comment: I was being facetious :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference between the stem or blossom end, you should save the end which looks and feels in the best shape.

Answer (score 2):

This was going to be my first comment on Seasoned Advice, but after reading the preface about writing answers, I'm wondering if 55 years of every-day family cooking qualifies me. Forging ahead fearlessly and with nothing to back me up except personal habit, save the root ends of onions, the blossom ends of cukes and tomatoes.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You wouldn't have been able to write a comment, we require a bit of reputation for it, while answers and questions are open to everybody. While we prefer answers to have a well founded explanation (it's entirely possible to do something for 55 years out of habit, not because it's the best solution), this certainly qualifies as an answer. Every reader has to decide for themselves how believable they find it.